# Should a session be required for user forms

Tags: php, forms, session, zend-framework, csrf

We have an application written in php using Zend Framework 1.12. Zend automatically creates a session for each guest. In the case were an anonymous guest can spend some decent amount of time on the same page filling out a lengthly form, would it be considered safe practice to simply extend the session timeout to something like a few hours, or even an entire day, just for anonymous guests?

The data collected via the form is not user sensitive data, think about it like a glorified "contact us" form. We are using CSRF tokens, which is why we need the session to remain active while the user fills out the form. Unfortunately, it's not an option break the form out into multiple smaller forms.

The problem I need to solve, is that the user's session may expire before they submit the form, and the csrf is no longer valid.

Comment: It looks like for anonymous guests the security concern should be minimal. There is a way to set the expiration for the CSRF (so that you extend it more than the default). It is called `timeout`,  part of `csrf_options`

Comment: The issue, is that the csrf token is stored in the session. If the session is garbage collected before the user submits their form, there's no longer a csrf token to compare, and the form fails. This is what I need to prevent.